# You can implement missing steps with the snippets below shows in console even after implementing it

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I had created three files .feature file, stepDefinition.java and testRunner.java. when i try to run the testRunner class it keeps on showing the suggestion in console like You can implement missing steps with the snippets below: with steps in feature file. The irony is I already implemented all the steps in a stepDefinition. can anyone help me with this?

login.feature

```
Feature: Amazon login feature
Scenario: Valid and invalid test cases
Given user already in login page
When user enters username 
Then user enters password
Then user click login page
```

stepDefinitions.java

```
package stepDefinition;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class stepdefinitions {
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    @Given("^user already in login page$")
    public void user_already_in_login_page() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\MuthuKumar\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");       
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList"))).click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign in']"))).build().perform();

    }
    @When("^user enters username$")
    public void user_enters_username() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys("8526606990");
        driver.findElement(By.id("continue")).click();
    }

    @Then("^user enters password$")
    public void user_enters_password() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys("sample");
    }

    @Then("^user click login page$")
    public void user_click_login_page() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();
    }
}
```

testRunners.java

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features= {"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Cucumber2222\\src\\test\\java\\feature"},glue= {"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Cucumber2222\\src\\test\\java\\stepDefinition"})
public class testRunners {

}
```

console message

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^user already in login page$")
public void user_already_in_login_page() throws Exception {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^user enters username$")
public void user_enters_username() throws Exception {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^user enters password$")
public void user_enters_password() throws Exception {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^user click login page$")
public void user_click_login_page() throws Exception {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Comment: If `stepDefinition.java` is as posted, then you should be receiving a compiler error. Because `stepDefinition.java` can only contain a class named `stepDefinition`; not one named `stepdefinitions`.

Comment: The actual name of the class is stepDefinitions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving a path in glue, Just give your **package name**. it works fine

testRunners.java

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features= {"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Cucumber2222\\src\\test\\java\\feature"}
,glue= {"stepDefinition"})
public class testRunners {

}
```